# Quote Form display none media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have developed a custom quote form for a client and when the user scroll down I add a class called .quoteform-fixed it also has an id called #quoteForm however I am trying to hide the entire quote form using media queries. Here is the css I am using....

```
@media screen and (max-width:1670px) and (min-width:1199px){
  .quoteform-fixed {display:none !important}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1198px) and (min-width:767px){
  .quoteform-fixed {display:none !important}
}
@media screen and (max-width:766px) and (min-width:220px){
  .quoteform-fixed {display:none !important}
}
```

Here is the main rules for quoteform-fixed...

```
.quoteform-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35px;
  right: 35px;
  display: block;
}
```

here is the form HTML...

```
<div id="quoteForm" class="quote-form">
  <div id="quoteFormHead"></div>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
      <div id="quoteFormBody">
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="text" name="message_fname" placeholder="Enter your full name here...">
        </div>
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="email" name="message_email" placeholder="Enter your email address here...">
        </div>
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="number" name="message_phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number here...">
        </div>
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <textarea name="message_msg" placeholder="Details, please! Audience? Word count? Type of document? Tone? Deadlines? Sensitive content?"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="quoteFormFooter">
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="submit" id="submitform" value="Get my free quote">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

And here is the Javascript to add the class on scroll...

```
window.onscroll = function(){
  var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var form = document.getElementById('quoteForm');
  if (top > 800) {
    form.classList.add("quoteform-fixed");
  } else {
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-fixed");
  }
}
```

Many thanks,
Phillip

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Don't forget to include the HTML needed to demonstrate the problem. Use the stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo.

Comment: Please share the usage of `quoteform-fixed`. Directly copying the above media queries to a snippet worked immediately. (Warning: Opinion incoming) It may be easier to be less restrictive for the media queries

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why you are adding three media queries to apply the same property, but creating it with the max and min flipped should work.

```css
form {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 600px;
  background: tomato;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  .quoteform-fixed {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class='quoteform-fixed'>
</form>
```

Comment: The reason I am using three media queries is because I want quoteform-fixed to display:none on all of those screen sizes, I will also be adding other rules to those media queries. Also I am using the same rules you have answered in my question but nothing works.

Comment: If you look at the range of your 3 queries, you are trying to cover everything from 220px to 1670px to display:none. You don't need three separate media queries for that.

Comment: You can also use inspector on your browser to see if the media query is being applied. If it is grayed out or strikethrough, you might get a hint why it's not working. Maybe you have a specificity issue if the other display has an !important too.